# Having <?php tags inside a js .html() method?

Tags: php, javascript

If we have:

```
html('<a href="blabla.org">go here</a>')
```

Can we have `<?php` tags inside inside href on this case, or it's a bad practice?

Thanks.
MEM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have those, sure. Just know that the code inside it will be executed on the server, before the JS is executed. So if you have:

```
html('<a href="blabla.org"><?php echo 'go here'; ?></a>')
```

Your Javascript will become:

```
html('<a href="blabla.org">go here</a>')
```

You can't influence the PHP code at the time the JS is executed.

Comment: Wow. I see. :) Nice. I was thinking about mounting the href="" address dynamically, so I can do that because it will execute the php part, and then, "mount" (how can we say this properly?) the html element. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

theres nothing wrong with it but we do like to have some standards on writing php within view logic.

Firstly you should familiarize your self `while` / `for` / `if` / `else` / `foreach` loops within the alternative syntax.

This gives a more clearer prospective on html / php combined code., Example Below

```
<?php if ($a == 5): ?>
    <b>HTML</b> Here <br />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Theres also another trick that helps you keep your code clear and that's short tags but its not switched on in most conmen php server configurations so you have to make sure

```
html('<a href="blabla.org"><?=$blabla?></a>')
```

Have a look for yourself:

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: I'm on a learning process myself. And for that reason, I really prefer to have long lines of code that has all explained etc... ;) But I'm looking forward into writing a more standardised way. For example, the endif; and endfor; usage, I found them quite pratical when between them, we have a long list of html lines. Far better then having the misterious <?php } ?> But, even on those cases, I profit to comment them, like: <?php } //end of if X ?> - cheers.